# Clickable dots on an image with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an image like this one:

[image]

I want to make every dot clickable with different URL and furthermore I would like to implement a pop up text when the mouse is over one dot.

How can I do that with javascript and css? Any library?

Comment: Yes you can, but I think is much better use svg to do this.

Comment: http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/

Comment: check this [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by online mapping tool for your image.

I have tried to map your image from [this](http://www.image-maps.com/) link.

You can see I have made a clickable link on a couple of dots and set custom text as the title to display text on hover.

I hope this will help you. Thanks.

```html
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2017-04-25-084654" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FbxJg.png" border="0" width="286" height="322" orgWidth="286" orgHeight="322" usemap="#image-maps-2017-04-25-084654" alt="" />
<map name="image-maps-2017-04-25-084654" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2017-04-25-084654">
<area  alt="" title="custom-text" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="rect" coords="228,156,255,181" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area  alt="" title="custom-text" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="rect" coords="129,173,156,198" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
<area shape="rect" coords="284,320,286,322" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a small example for you.  You can do this in native HTML.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}

.container img {
  width:200px;
}

.dot {
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px;
  background:black;
  border:1px solid white;
  border-radius:50%;
  font-size:0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
  transition: all 2s;
}

.dot:hover {
  text-indent: auto;
  width:auto;
  font-size:12px;
  z-index:1;
  border-radius:0;
}
```

```html
<div  class="container">
  <img src="https://images.craigslist.org/00808_ha1rdMjpXZR_1200x900.jpg" />
  <div class="dot" style="left:10px;top:10px;">
    I'm testing code
  </div>
  <div class="dot" style="left:50px;top:50px;">
    I'm testing code2
  </div>
  <div class="dot" style="left:10px;top:70px;">
    I'm testing code3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML tag to do so, Please check the  tag in html it might serve your purpose.

Check the below code may help you:

[Demo Link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap)

And you can also use `<canvas>` or `<svg>` with the help of [Fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1) you can get the thing done in much more advance way.

Check this link you will get really cool stuff to do with image or canvas and svg:

[MDN - Canvas API Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial)

Thanks

```js
function runfunc(planetId) {
  console.log('You selected:', planetId);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 2.8em !important; }
```

```html
<p>Click on the Sun or on one of the planets to see which one was selected.</p>

<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" width="145" height="126"
     alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" id="Sun" onclick="runfunc(this.id)">
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" id="Mercury" onclick="runfunc(this.id)">
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" id="Venus" onclick="runfunc(this.id)">
</map>
```